# SQL Server Extended Events Sessions on VIEWs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, extended-events

I'm trying to monitor when Views are being called in SQL Server.

Using Extended Events, I've created a Session and included event "sql_statement_completed".

Then I've added 1x filters on this:

> sqlserver.database_name | equal_i_sql_unicode_string |
>   MyDatabaseNameHere

So the session logs all sql statements across that particular database.

**However, I'd like to only monitor when Views are being called. Ideally, something to track against *ObjectType = 8278***.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you following up on my answer here?https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185205/is-this-considered-a-light-load-trace-to-run-on-sql-server-profiler/185226#185226